# How can I use <time> tag in <input>'s value attribute?

Tags: html, input

I have an order form and I need to do something like this:

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" name="myInput" value='<time datetime="2015-01-01" itemprop="startDate">1.1.2015</time>' class="width-100" readonly />
```

but in the browser, in the input area, where should be displayed just: `1.1.2015`, as I supposed, is displayed the whole time tag: `<time datetime="2015-01-01" itemprop="startDate">1.1.2015</time>`

...idk why, and I can't figure out how to make this work.

The time tag in input's value is based on date selected from DB and returned by function, like: `return '<time datetime="'.date('Y-m-d', strtotime($from)).'" itemprop="startDate">'.date('j.n.Y', strtotime($from)).'</time>';`

Any advice would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: You can write almost anything you want inside an HTML attribute, as long as you *encode* it properly (e.g. `&lt;` instead of `<`, etc.). But `<input>` elements are designed to hold plain text. Are you 100% sure you want to display raw HTML tags to the user? What for?

Comment: the `value` is interpreted as a string, you can't have tags inside `value` property. why don´t you use just `value="1.1.2015"`?

Comment: I have to carry that datetime and itemprop values while posting the form, is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: `<input type="hidden">`?

Comment: Right, I've composed a proper answer, now the question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can write almost anything you want inside an HTML attribute, as long as you encode it properly (e.g. `&lt;` instead of `<`, `&quot;` instead of `"`, etc.). All decent programming languages provide built-in methods to take care of the dirty details. Whether those values are valid, meaningful or useful in the context of the precise attribute is a different thing.

`<input>` elements are designed to hold plain text. Whatever you write into the `value` attribute will be rendered to the user as-is. If you type HTML tags, you'll display HTML code, nothing else.

If you want to send form data to the server, you can simply use form fields, as you are already doing. The missing bit is that form fields do not need to be visible. There's a specific control for hidden data: `<input type="hidden">`. From [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FElement%2FInput):

> `hidden`: A control that is not displayed, but whose value is submitted to the server.